# How to do a list with all categories and subcategories, from a given main-category

Tags: category, collection

I like to do a list with the name of all subcategories and sub subcategories from a giving main category.

I am really a bit new in Magento. But what I want to do, a list from all subcategories (name and url, as href) from the main category "Brands":

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/

without the "All Brands" category but with those subcategories from "All Brands".

Any suggestions or link I can find some solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Assume the ID of category "All Brands" is 3

```
    $parentCategoryId = 3;
    $childCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parentCategoryId);

  foreach ($childCategories as $child) {
        echo 'Name : ' . $child->getName() . '<br>'; // will print the sub category name
        echo 'Url : ' . $child->getRequestPath() . '<br><hr>'; // will print the URL
    }
```

NOTE: If you want to get more info about the sub category use below lines inside above foreach() loop.

```
$subCatData = $child->getData();
```

It will get an array of sub category data.

> EDIT:

If you are in the category page you can get the current category ID by using below line of code. (instead of hard-coding the category ID use this way)

```
$ccurrentCategoryId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```

So now the code would be as follows in your scenario.

```
 $parentCategoryId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        $childCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parentCategoryId);

      foreach ($childCategories as $child) {
            echo 'Name : ' . $child->getName() . '<br>'; // will print the sub category name
            echo 'Url : ' . $child->getRequestPath() . '<br><hr>'; // will print the URL
        }
```

Comment: I get now all parent categories, so Brands, Acitivities, Mens, etc, instead of the child categories of Brands.

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/

Comment: Did you use ID of `Brands` as `$parentCategoryId` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, it is really 3. But any other number I put in, no change. Here is the result:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

Comment: It's strange,, plz check the edited code

Answer (score 0):

To get a collection of subcategories of a given category `$parentCategory`, use:

```
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1) // remove this to go deeper
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%']);
```

(as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5564647/664108)

As noted in the code comment above, you can use the `level` filter  to specify how deep you want to recurse into subcategories. To get subcategories and sub-sub-categories but not sub-sub-subcategories, use this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('level', ['lte' => $parentCategory->getLevel() + 2])
```

(`lte` stands for *less than or equal*)

If you want to show the categories sorted by parent like this

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2 2
2.1
```

add this line:

```
$subcategoryCollection->setOrder('path', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

Depending on what data you need to display, select the attributes to select:

```
$subcategoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'description', 'image']);
```

You can always select all attributes with `addAttributeToSelect('*')` instead, but I don't recommend it because it results in unneccessary queries to the EAV tables.

Then you can `foreach` over `$subcategoryCollection` and display the subcategories however you wish.

#### Example template:

```
<?php foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: So, how it could be the php code, when I like to list all subcategories on a cms page?

Comment: You can't write PHP code in a CMS page. But you can create a `phtml` template and include it in the CMS page with the `{{block}}` directive. Use the PHP code from my answer in that template, the only thing missing is initialization of `$parentCategory` (for example: `$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);`)

Comment: If I put this, I just get nothing, what else do I need to set? I use it on a cms page:

<?php 

$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 2)
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%']);

<?php foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: You can't write PHP code in a CMS page

Comment: yes, I do like this. so, it will be like:

<?php 
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1) // remove this to go deeper
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%']);
foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: It "works" now so far... only I get the links but not the "name/title"...

Comment: Use `var_dump($category->getData());` to see what data is available.

Comment: I did now the follow way: and it does, what I need so far. Only need to sort it a bit, to get the follow result:

http://www.outdoorequipped.com/info/our_brands

<?php    
    $brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>

<?php foreach($brands as $brand): ?>
    
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $brand->getUrl() ?>">
             <?php echo htmlspecialchars($brand->getName()) ?>
    <?php echo var_dump($brand->getData()); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 <?php endforeach ?>

Comment: Except that this does not give you subsubcategories.

Comment: Exactly, but on this I can work on. Your solution didn't give me the name...

Comment: okay, my overall goal is, to get this done: http://www.outdoorequipped.com/info/our_brands

I am open to learn something. Right at the moment, It seem's as I am the only like to have something like this.

Comment: Ah I know why, forgot to select the attributes: `$subcategoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect(['name']);`, add other attributes to the array if needed.

Comment: with this code:

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1)
  ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%'])
  ->addAttributeToSelect(['name'])
  ->setOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

I get some good result.

Comment: Still not what I need: https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

- Need to figure out, how I can see categories I have "under" "View All Brands"
- And need to try to list per character, A, all names with A, B with B.